# How to start run onLocationChanged method by onClick

Tags: android, google-maps

I have `onLocationChanged()` method inside my `MapsActivity` that draws polyline everytime user location is moving, but i want it trigger by `Start` button, so it does not draw everytime on Map, when the drawing Polyline is over, user click `Stop` Button. and then run `distanceBetween()` method to the draw polyline. and when user click start button again, it `.clear();` the map, and start all over again,  I have manage the drawing polyline parts, the distanceBetween() parts, but i don't know how to trigger by start and stop button the drawpolyline inside onLocationChanged() method, How do i do this?

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
        }
        latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        latA = latLng.latitude;
        longA = latLng.longitude;
        tvlattitude.setText(""+latA);
        tvlongitude.setText(""+longA);

        listPointsB.add(latLng);
        pOptions = new PolylineOptions()
                .width(5)
                .color(Color.BLUE)
                .geodesic(true);
        for (int z = 0; z < listPointsB.size(); z++) {
            LatLng point = listPointsB.get(z);
            pOptions.add(point);
        }
        line = mMap.addPolyline(pOptions);
//        Toast.makeText(this, "Location Changed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

and this is the button

```
Button bStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btStart);
        bStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        Button bStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btStop);
        bStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //
            }
        });
```

Comment: You might want to reword your question its not very clear

Comment: wait, i'll try more specific

Answer (score 0):

Try using [FusedLocationProviderClient](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current#java)